# Accessing/Calling a class method from another class in mediator pattern javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, design-patterns, mediator

```
class Customer {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    send(amount, to) {
        new GooglePay().send(amount, this, to);
    }
    receive(amount, from) {
        console.log(`Payment of ${amount} from ${from} to ${this.name} is succesful`);
    }
}
```

the problem is based on mediator pattern.
so above i have defined my customer who can send and receive money. So I have built a class called GooglePay which mediates transaction between customers.
Customer have send function through which they can send money, it takes 2 arguments (amount ,to)

The function should actually then invoke or be received by the GooglePay instance which then sends the amount to the receiver after checking if the receiver has registered

```
class GooglePay {
    constructor() {
        this.customerBase = [];
    }
    register(name) {
        this.customerBase.push(name);
        return this;
    }
    send(amount, from, to) {
        if (this.customerBase.filter(cust => cust === to)) {
            to.receive(amount, from);
        } else {
            console.log('This customer does not exist');
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me out, I'm stuck and I dont understand how i can access methods of other classes from a class.

Comment: `const pay = new GooglePay();pay.register(...); pay.send(100, new Customer(), new Customer());`

Comment: Yes I understand your approach, but what if I wanted to call from customer for eg: ```pay.register(jonas); jonas.send(100, 'Wilms'); ```I hope you get where i am trying to go.  I want the customer to make the call, because otherwise if i go with ```pay.send(100, new cust(), new cust()); ``` then i have to input both the sender and receiver. I want to send through the cust and receive back to him. mediator just receives the request and checks in database if the receiver actually exist and is registered with google pay. Kindly help me out.

Comment: that doesn't make much sense though.

Comment: I want to make it as lively as possible, i want the customers to be able to directly send and receive payments, like if i can do something like ```pay.register(....).send( amount, to)``` it makes more sense when you think of practical application

Answer (score 0):

So i have found the correct solution for my problem, check it out:

```
class Customer {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.googlepay = null;
    }
    send_money(amount, to) {
        this.googlepay.transaction(amount, this, to);
    }
    receive_money(amount, from) {
        console.log(`payment of ${amount} from ${from} to ${this.name} is succesful`);
    }
}

class GooglePay {
    constructor() {
        this.customer_base = [];
    }
    register_customer(customer_class) {
        this.customer_base.push(customer_class);
        customer_class.googlepay = this;
    }
    transaction(amount, from, to) {
        this.customer_base.filter(cust => {
            if (cust.name === to) {
                cust.receive_money(amount, from.name);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

on close observation you can see a property in my customer class constructor called `this.googlepay = null`

That's where the trick lies. Cheerios mate
Great solving the puzzle.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't matter if you're using any frameworks, if you want to call a `js` class  (since [ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)). To call functions or properties from a class, you can go like:

```js
//expecting that the class is in another file but same directory
const Gpay = require('./googlePay'); //<-- don't need the .js file extension
const googlePay = new GPay();
```

Now you can use the class like this:

```js
googlePay.register('Name');
```

Comment: Yes I understand your approach, but what if I wanted to call from customer for eg: ```pay.register(jonas); jonas.send(100, 'Wilms'); ```I hope you get where i am trying to go.  I want the customer to make the call, because otherwise if i go with ```pay.send(100, new cust(), new cust()); ``` then i have to input both the sender and receiver. I want to send through the cust and receive back to him. mediator just receives the request and checks in database if the receiver actually exist and is registered with google pay. Kindly help me out.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you could put a new customer in a variable and pass it to the pay class like `const jonas = new Customer('Jonas');` and `pay.send(jonas);`. But please note that you have to receive new customer in pay method.